# Share Intent destroys Activity

Tags: android, share, startactivityforresult, android-ondestroy

I am using several share intents in my application but when ever I share and my application moves in background and after sharing the activity destroys.
I've tried:

`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"`

and

`android:noHistory="true"`

for the particular activity and calling explicit intents like e.g for (google+, facebook, twitter and email)

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Send mail..."),4);
```

and my **ActivityOnResult**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==FB_SIGN_ING){
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    } //else do nothing
}
```

**Update:**
Ive figured it out a little bit my activity destroys when move to background to front. but how to handle it even if I m using particular configurations and **ActivityOnResult**.

intent Example:

```
public void ShareByEmail(){
        final String newsTitle = singleNews.get(0).getNews_title().trim();
        String newsPhoto=SingleNewsImages.get(0);
        String url = BASE_URL+newsPhoto;
        final String newsLink = "http://motorcityarabia.com"+singleNews.get(0).getLink().trim();
        final Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        Target target = new Target() {
            @Override public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

               // Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,Uri.parse("mailto:"));
                Intent intent = new Intent();
              intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,newsTitle);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT , Html.fromHtml("<strong><a href='"+newsLink+"'>"+newsTitle+"</a></strong><br/><a href='"+newsLink+"'>READ MORE</a>"));

                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getLocalBitmapUri(bitmap));
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Send mail..."),4);


            }
            @Override public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                Toast.makeText(SingleNewsActivity.this, "Error Drawable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                Toast.makeText(SingleNewsActivity.this, "Prepairing Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url).into(target);


    }
```

Comment: Please post your stack

Comment: how to get the stack

Comment: what is the error you are getting??

Comment: Im not geting any errors the intents are sharing the posts and even email is oing but when it returns back the particular activity on destroy is called

Comment: i think you are calling finish() before opening new activity?? check for that

Comment: have updated the question

Comment: post some code before startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Send mail..."),4);

Comment: here may be you are calling finish()

Comment: Try set your android:noHistory="false", setting it true will cause activity to destroy after you navigate away.

Comment: Is there any other solutions? android:noHistory="false" didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Add following in your manifiest

```
 <application......android:noHistory="false">....</application>
```

Comment: Please pay attention that your answer has already been mentioned in comments in 2016. Try to elaborate more on why it is the solution.Also, note that the question is asked 3 years ago.